# Authentication in MVC 3: Which way to roll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have written a set of Interfaces and associated clases to Authenticate users using Entity Framework rather that the sotred procs provided with the builtin and rather dated ASP.NET Membership provider.

What would be the best way to implement my AuthenticationService with my MVC 3 application?
Should I write a custom provider and override the Membership Provider? This looks easy but I don't really care for the provider factory of factories model that Microsoft has given us.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is it too late for you to use OpenId?

Comment: No, I don't suppose. I still need to keep a skeleton profile etc for my site members however, but I suppose I can figure out a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my own membership service based on the interface that came with MVC 2. Since authorization in my application is a little more complicated than the out of the box role-based stuff, I couldn't use the `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider`. I still use FormsAuthentication though for keeping track of the logged in user. You lose out on being able to use the `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` and other framework bits, but like I said my application doesn't use Role based auth.

```
public class MyMembershipService : IMembershipService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    public MyMembershipService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public virtual bool IsValid(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = userRepository.FindByUsername(username);

        return user != null && user.PasswordMatches(password);
    }

    public virtual bool AllowedToLogIn(string username)
    {
        var user = userRepository.FindByUsername(username) ?? new User();

        return user.AllowedToLogIn();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar, already have everything ready to roll, however I can't get FormsAuthentication to remeber the logged onuser when passing createPersistentCookie.

Comment: This is a different issue altogether then.. I assume you already checked if the cookies are enabled and that the cookie is present in the request collection.. You can give a try to session as well if that is an option...

Comment: The FormsAuthentication HttpModule sets the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name on subsequent requests to the value you set in SetAuthCookie.

Comment: I will make another post for this issue. I am not thinking it is a problem with my code. I see the cookie getting set in the browser when I call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(logonModel.UserName,true);

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good time to look into [Access Control Service (ACS) 2.0](http://acs.codeplex.com/), it provides you with SSO and centralized authentication. It just went into production release and it is free until end of the year. Works great with MVC3, you will need to get Windows Identity Foundation. There are plenty of resources online of how to integrate it. Great blog post to get you started, [Announcing the commercial release of Windows Azure AppFabric Caching and Access Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazureappfabric/archive/2011/04/11/announcing-the-commercial-release-of-windows-azure-appfabric-caching-and-access-control.aspx).

Comment: This looks like a cloud based answer from Microsoft to OpenID, which is very cool. However this application I am working on, ACS would be a bit ovekill... I am still going to look in to this though; Way cool.